# Structuring of a single integral for a sectioned sphere

Tags: integration

There are several ways of obtaining the volume of sphere above a predetermined plane.

The image below describes my idea:

[image]

I made the integral of the sphere and then I make the integral of a cone and add the volumes

**Integral of the sphere:**

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{50}\int_0^{3\pi/4}r^2 \sin \phi \;d\phi\;dr\;d\theta$

> $446920\;mm^3$

**Integral of the cone:**

$x=\sqrt{1250}$

$y=\sqrt{1250}$

$\int_0^{\sqrt{1250}} \frac{\pi  x^2 z^2}{y^2} \, dz$

> $46280\;mm^3$

**Total:**

$446920\;mm^3+46280\;mm^3=493200\;mm^3$

**How do I structure a single integral to get this result?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$\displaystyle V = \int_{r\cos\theta}^r \pi \left(r^2-x^2\right) dx = \frac{\pi}{3} r^3 (2-3\cos\theta+\cos^3\theta) = \frac{\pi}{3} r^3 (2+\cos\theta) (1-\cos\theta)^2$

Answer (score 2):

In this case it is more convenient to use cylindrical coordinates.

If you place the centre of the spare in the origin, than the bottom section is at $z=-R/\sqrt{2}$.

The integral of the volume has than the form:
$$
V = \int_{-R/\sqrt{2}}^R dz \int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-z^2}} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi r \\
= \int_{-R/\sqrt{2}}^R dz \int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-z^2}} dr (2 \pi r)  \\
= \int_{-R/\sqrt{2}}^R dz \pi (R^2 - z^2) \\
= \frac{2\pi R^3}{3} + \frac{5\pi R^6}{6 \sqrt{2}}
$$
with all integrals easy to integrate.